# google maps - function geocode and marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I need pass variable markers[x] and infoWindowContent[x] in place of the string "Title Markers" and "Text Window".

Using markers [x] or infoWindowContent[x] value is undefined.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

```
function initialize(addresses, zoom_s) {

    // Multiple Markers
    var markers = [
        ['London Eye, London'],
        ['Palace of Westminster, London']
    ];

    // Info Window Content
    var infoWindowContent = [
        ['<div class="info_content"><h3>London Eye</h3><p>The London Eye is a giant Ferris wheel situated on the banks of the River Thames. The entire structure is 135 metres (443 ft) tall and the wheel has a diameter of 120 metres (394 ft).</p></div>'],
        ['<div class="info_content"><h3>Palace of Westminster</h3><p>The Palace of Westminster is the meeting place of the House of Commons and the House of Lords, the two houses of the Parliament of the United Kingdom. Commonly known as the Houses of Parliament after its tenants.</p></div>']
    ];

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var myOptions = {
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    };

    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    if (geocoder) {
        // Display multiple markers on a map
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
            marker, i;
        var marker_testo = "";
        var info_testo = "";

        for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {

            var marker_testo = addresses[x];

            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': addresses[x]
            }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            map: map,
                            title: "Title Markers"

                        });

                        // Allow each marker to have an info window    
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, x) {
                            return function () {
                                infoWindow.setContent("Text Window");
                                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, x));

                        // Automatically center the map fitting all markers on the screen
                        bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);

                        map.fitBounds(bounds);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Override our map zoom level once our fitBounds function runs (Make sure it only runs once)
        var boundsListener = google.maps.event.addListener((map), 'bounds_changed', function (event) {
            this.setZoom(14);
            google.maps.event.removeListener(boundsListener);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two hardcoded markers, and two hardcoded pieces of content.  But you accept an array of addresses - will this always have exactly 2 addresses too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var markers = [
    'London Eye, London',
    'Palace of Westminster, London'
];

console.log(markers[0]);
```

There is no need for the barckets inside of your array. Please check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

How your array is constructed, you would need to use `markers[0][0]` or `markers[1][0]` etc.

**Edit:**

To complete my answer, here is a way to achieve what you want. Create a counter and increment it *within* the geocoder result and create a new variable to hold the contents of the infoWindow.

```
var iwContent = infoWindowContent[counter];

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: results[0].geometry.location,
    map: map,
    title: addresses[counter]
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {

    infoWindow.setContent(iwContent);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});

counter++;
```

See my [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/D4f7G/).

Comment: What does `addresses` look like? Shouldn't it be `markers` instead?

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous. So basically your loop will end before the geocoder returns anything.

Comment: See my updated answer and don't forget to accept it if it answered your question :) Thanks.

Comment: I've added a lot of markers. 
Do you know if there is a limit to the items to display on the map 
?   http://jsfiddle.net/D4f7G/4/

Comment: When displaying markers on a map, it's always better to have the coordinates and not to use the geocoder when you can. There are limits ([see this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits)). Also you should think about storing your markers in a database and use JSON to retrieve them. It will be more flexible and easier to maintain.